# NSEntityMigrationPolicy vs NSEntityMapping

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, core-data-migration

*To whoever has a good understanding of the migration process of `Core Data`:*

What's the difference (what are their respective roles and their difference) between `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` and `NSEntityMapping`?

*I don't have any specific problem. I am just curious.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSEntityMapping` describes the transformation between entities, attributes and relationships.

`NSEntityMigrationPolicy` describes the particular process that should be followed when applying the mappings. With the policy you customize the particular stages of the migration life cycle.

In a way it is similar the life cycle callbacks of view controllers. E.g. controllers have views, application logic, etc. but you can inject custom code manipulating these in methods like `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillDisappear`, `dealloc`, etc. if you have to do something at particular stages in the life cycle of the view.

Similarly, `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` has methods like **begin**EntityMapping:, **end**RelationshipCreationForDestinationInstance:, etc.